# OpenSSH on Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick): should ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file be generated automatically?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm setting up public key authentication using this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys.

The documentation talks about the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, but there is no `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is my home directory.

Should this file be generated automatically?

The [Maverick sshd man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/sshd.8.html) does not specify whether the file is created when OpenSSH is installed, or whether the file should be created manually.

I just wondered if the absence of this file is normal before I create it myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is a per-user file. Installing a unix program never writes to users' home directories. So by default the file will not exist (which has the same effect as an empty file).

If you're generating the key on a client that is also running OpenSSH, use `ssh-copy-id` [[as described](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Transfer%20Client%20Key%20to%20Host)] to transfer the public key to the server, using for that one time your password to log into the server.

If you're generating the key by some other method, copy the `id_rsa.pub` file from where you generated the key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server (create the directory `~/.ssh` if necessary). Make sure that all three of your home directory, `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` are writable only to the user (no group or other write permissions). If you want to authorize more than one key, just concatenate them into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (so `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` has one public key per line).

If you use something other than OpenSSH to generate the key, you might need to convert the public key to the OpenSSH format. For example, in PuTTY, use  [‘Public key for pasting into authorized_keys file’](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-pastekey).

Comment: Excellent response, thanks for your help. That makes sense.

Comment: to highlight one of the points mentioned above: "no group or other write permissions" -- having group write permission on the authorized_keys file was the only thing preventing public key authentication from working on a machine here and had me running in circles.  +1!

Answer (score 3):

From that page:

> The private key is kept on the computer you log in from, while *the public key is stored on the .ssh/authorized_keys file* on all the computers you want to log in to.

When creating a keyfile using `ssh-keygen`, you'll get files named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. The first is your private key (possibly password-protected) and should be kept secret all times. You are the *client*.

The latter is your public key which can be given to the other side, the *server*. The server can allow multiple public keys. The key files are plaintext files, so you can open them with any text-editor. The public keyfile has just one line, this line should be added to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the *server*.

The private and public keys below are generated using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. The previous command created the files `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

A private key file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` looks like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,6D5AD2DF5464E16B4E92E81D095A5E7E

NbCawtGTPOfveFHvV93uw5/veo/fAmbZEcitpNlq/rPEy8ZLo7/0MltFDUupe6dI
...23 lines omitted...
eiau+K6IAbhp84/6ewXPVJ6JbfeS9vyOqkcPaZDlQ3rvbAxU9dfTptc/ZWxVoCDg
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The corresponding public key `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` looks like:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EA[some chars omitted]X3aKKB6lOyr0v user@host
```

The first word is either `ssh-rsa` (for RSA keys) or `ssh-dss` (for DSA keys). The second part (`AAAAB3...r0v`) is the actual data. `user@host` is just a comment, and could be replaced with anything, like `sysadmin from home`.

Answer (score 1):

Just create it using your favorite editor or `touch`, but make sure it has the right permissions.

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea, its normal. Simply create one when you want to add ssh-keys.